# Como posso criar uma tabela temporária em meu SQL na estrutura Query Builder do CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

tudo bem com vocês?
Estou enfrentando um problema, e não acho alternativas...

Eu tenho uma query em SQL funcionando, estou colocando ela dentro de um sistema, desenvolvido em [CodeIgniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/welcome.html), mas tem uma parte específica dessa minha query que eu não consigo migrar para a estrutura do CodeIgniter...

No meu caso, seria a sintaxe "*with*" do SQL, para criar uma "tabela temporária".

```
with tabela_tmp as (
    select 'exemplo' AS linha
    ...
)
```

Eu já tentei colocar a minha query inteira dentro de um:

```
$this->db->query("minha query");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Mas por algum motivo é gerado esse erro:

> Must specify table to select from.

### Atualmente estou tentando dessa maneira:

```
$this->db->select("minha query");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

É gerado erro, pois a sintaxe "*with*" está retornando dento do "*SELECT*"

> Incorrect syntax near 'tabela_tmp'.

```
SELECT TOP 10 with tabela_tmp as ( ... ) SELECT * FROM table ...
```

Então, como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Por acaso, não está falanto o SELECT que retorna o conteúdo da tabela_temp?  `with tabela_tmp as ( select 'exemplo' AS linha ...) select * from tabela_tmp`

Comment: Em minha query eu faço um `LEFT JOIN` com a minha `tabela_tmp`, então não.